# Cannot save underscore custom fields in one wordpress installation using xmlrpc and underscores

Tags: custom-field, xml-rpc

I have a local installation of wordpress for testing and a production server.

I use XMLRPC to create custom posts with custom fields and everything works flawlessly on my local installation BUT it doesn't work for the production server. Custom Fields are not saved, I checked the table and it doesn't store it.

Is related to the underscores present in the start of the custom fields, for example:
`_al_listing_price`

I have tried to store a custom field `al_listing_price` and it was saved in the database.

Where I can disable that behavior so it allow to post prefixed underscore  custom fields?

Comment: Does WordPress version, theme and active plugins differ on local and production servers?

Comment: Yes, for the record I have fixed with register_meta function using this plugin https://gist.github.com/hugocf/4726663

Answer (score 1):

You have to unprotect meta to be able to access it with XML-RPC:

```
<?php

function my_unprotect_meta( $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type ) {

    if( '_al_listing_price' == $meta_key ) {
        return false;
    }

}

add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'my_unprotect_meta', 10, 3 );
```

The solution you've mentioned in the comment to the question is 'duct tape' though it works. It completely removes meta value sanitization, which is the bad idea.